# What does it mean to say "almost always" ?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

I have a set, $A$, of $m \times n$ matrices with certain properties and a subset $B$ of $A$. I would like to say that when randomly selecting such a matrix, I am "almost always" never in $B$. I can show that $A$ is the disjoint union of subsets, $A_j$, such that for each $A_j$, the measure of $A_j\cap B$ is 0. However, this union is uncountable. Is this enough to reasonably conclude that my randomly selected matrix will "almost always" never be in $B$?

Thanks for the help!

Best,
Julie

Additional info: Each $A_j$ has the following properties :

- the interior of $A_j$ is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$
- $\partial A_j = A_j\cap B$.

Comment: If you allow uncountably many sets just to get what you claim you could make the Ah's singletons. So, by itself this cannot possibly tell much. I am afraid without further details there is not much specufuc to answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I have added some more information to my question.

Best,
Julie

Comment: Your additional info imply that $A_j$ is an open set which contains its boundary, making it closed. Did you mean to write that $A_j$ is the closure of an open set?

Comment: $R^{mxn}$ is $\sigma$−compact so an uncountable open cover has a countable subcover. So you're good, right?

Comment: BTW, I don't understand your "Additional info."  An open set doesn't contain its boundary?!?  Right?

Comment: @ David and Yoav. 
Ah, thanks. I have updated my additional info.
 

Comment: This question still doesn't make sense. You can't have uncountably many disjoint open balls in euclidean space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some contradiction in your hypotheses: since the $A_j$'s are disjoint and have non empty interiors, the union should be at most countable (there can't exist more $A_j$'s than the cardinal of the set of rational points in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$).

Comment: Thanks, this illustrates a property of my problem that I had overlooked. It actually turns out that I have exactly one possible $A_j$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{U}$ denote the set of all open balls with rational centre and rational radius that are contained in $A_j$ for some $j$.  This is a countable family with the same union as the original family $\{A_j : j\in J\}$.  Now for $U\in\mathcal{U}$ we have $U\cap B\subseteq A_j\cap B$ for some $j$ so $U\cap B$ has measure zero.  As $\mathcal{U}$ is countable and covers $B$ we conclude that $B$ has measure zero.

UPDATE:  The answer above is correct if the sets $A_j$ are open, as in an earlier version of the question.  The current version seems to be consistent with the following example in which $B$ does not have measure zero:

- $n=m=1$
- $B=[0,\infty)$
- $A_t=(-\infty,0]\cup\{t\}$ for $t>0$

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the help. I may be mistaken, but it seems that $\mathcal{U}$ does not contain the points on the boundaries of the Aj?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Neil.

Answer (score 0):

No, an uncountable partition will, in general, not be enough.

For example, any set whatever can be partitioned into single-element subsets, each of measure zero.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. I have added some additional information to my question.